# derivative of a function as the limit of derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to figure out a proof of this using the fundamental theorem of calculus. Is is:

Supoose $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ is a sequence of differentiable function on $[a,b]$. If  $\lbrace f_n' \rbrace$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ and $\lbrace f_n(x_0) \rbrace$ converges for some $x_0 \in [a,b]$,  then $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on $[a,b]$, with $f'(x)= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f'_n(x)$.

I am just confused at this point... What  I am most confused on is how to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly.

What I have is this:

By FTC, we have $f_n(x)=f_n(x_0)+ \int_{x_0}^{x}f'_n(x)dx$ and taking the limit, by a previous theorem, we have $\lim {f_n(x)}= \lim({f_n(x_0)+ \int_{x_0}^{x}f'_n(x)dx)}=L+\int_{x_0}^{x}g(x)dx$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}, g$. But how does this show that $f_n$ converges uniformly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For any $x\in [a,b]$, one has
$$
f_n(x)=f_n(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xf'_n(x)dx.
$$

Solution: Fix $x\in[a,b]$ and define $y_n=\int_{x_0}^xf'_n(x)dx$. Now note that
$$|y_n-y_m|\le\int_{x_0}^x|f'_n(x)-f'_m(x)|dx\le (b-a) \sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f'_n(x)-f'_m(x)|.$$
As $f'_n$ converges uniformly to some function $g$, sequence $\{y_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and converges to some value $y(x)$ such that
$$|y_n-y(x)|\le (b-a) \sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f'_n(x)-g(x)|.$$
Thus, differentiable functions $f_n$ converges uniformly to the function $y(x)$. Thus $y(x)$ is a differentiable function and from Weierstrass, one has $f'_n$ converges uniformly to $y'(x)$. Due to uniqueness of limit, it yields that $y'(x)=g(x)$. (here $y\equiv f$)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fundamental theorem of calculus 
$$f(x)-f(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^x f'(t)dt$$